# how can we store a html page into sqlite in blackberry on memory card / phone memory?

Tags: sqlite, blackberry, java-me

Below code specifies that we we can make http connection in blackberry and how to store html page as a string?

I am doing this but I am able to get that http request but when I get response i.e http_ok it is not correct so that I can save text oh html as a string and I can further store that into sqlite.

```
LabelField title = new LabelField("SQLite Create Database Sample",
              LabelField.ELLIPSIS |
              LabelField.USE_ALL_WIDTH);
              setTitle(title);
              add(new RichTextField("Creating a database."));
              argURL="https://www.google.com:80";
            try {
                connDesc = connFact.getConnection(argURL);
                if (connDesc != null) {

                    httpConn = (HttpConnection) connDesc.getConnection();
                    // //Send Data on this connection
                    // httpConn.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET);
                    // //Server Response
                    StringBuffer strBuffer = new StringBuffer();
                    inStream = httpConn.openInputStream();
                    int chr;
                    int retResponseCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();
                    if (retResponseCode == HttpConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                        if (inStream != null) {
                            while ((chr = inStream.read()) != -1) {
                                strBuffer.append((char) chr);
                            }
                            serverResponceStr = strBuffer.toString();
                            // appLe.alertForms.get_userWaitAlertForm().append("\n"+serverResponceStr);

                            //returnCode = gprsConstants.retCodeSuccess;
                        }
                    } else {
                        //returnCode = gprsConstants.retCodeNOK;
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception excp) {
                //returnCode = gprsConstants.retCodeDisconn;
                excp.printStackTrace();
            } `enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0):

The code does not perform any database functionality, however I tested and it does successfully perform an HttpRequest to an external URL. The data that comes back is based on the response of the server you are making the request to.

The code I used can be found here:
http://snipt.org/vrl7

The only modifications is to keep a running summary of various events, and the response is displayed in the RichTextField. Basically, this looks to be working as intended, and the resulting String should be able to be saved however you see fit; though you may need to be cautious of encoding when saving to a database so that special characters are not lost or misinterpreted.